# Ola-issue of call API, but not response complitly

Tags: android

I am create android app,

I am sending `latitude` and `longitude` using below link with Token and
Authorization.

**Used Link :-**

```
http://sandbox-t.olacabs.com/v1/bookings/create?pickup_lat=23.1862&pickup_lng=72.6177&pickup_mode=NOW&category=sedan
```

But in i didn't get response please check and give me positive reply.
Below is I get the Response.

```
{"status": "FAILURE","code": "NO_CABS_AVAILABLE","message": "Sorry, the
ride you were trying to book is no longer available due to high demand.
Please try again."}
```

Comment: did you find any solution to this ? I'm to stuck on this same issue.